# How can I check which object is in my 2D Array in a certain index with Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am learning Java and I am trying creating a chess game.
How can I check which object is in the specified index of my array of cells objects?
I initialise all objects at start (one for each pawn), then when I move i want to say move whatever `pawn` is in the `cell c` to the `cell c` if it is free, if it is full, check if next is full and in that case delete eaten `pawn` and move my piece by 2 spaces.
The only thing is that i don't know how to do it...

```
package chess;
public class Main {
     public static Field field = new Field();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        field.create();
        resetStartCondition();
    }
    protected static void resetStartCondition() {
        int y = 0;
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++) {
            Field.cells[x][y].setFull(false);;
            y++; }
        // -- SPAWN ALL PIECES --- \\
        Tower towb1 = new Tower(0, Field.cells[7][0]);
        Tower towb2 = new Tower(0, Field.cells[7][7]);
        Tower town1 = new Tower(1, Field.cells[0][0]);
        Tower town2 = new Tower(1, Field.cells[0][7]);
        King kingb = new King(0, Field.cells[3][7]);
        King kingn = new King(1, Field.cells[3][0]);
        Queen queenb = new Queen(0, Field.cells[4][7]);
        Queen queenn = new Queen(1, Field.cells[4][0]);
        Horse horb1 = new Horse(0, Field.cells[1][7]);
        Horse horb2 = new Horse(0, Field.cells[6][7]);
        Horse horn1 = new Horse(1, Field.cells[1][0]);
        Horse horn2 = new Horse(1, Field.cells[6][0]);
        Alf alfb1 = new Alf(0, Field.cells[2][7]);
        Alf alfb2 = new Alf(0, Field.cells[5][7]);
        Alf alfn1 = new Alf(1, Field.cells[2][0]);
        Alf alfn2 = new Alf(1, Field.cells[5][0]);
        Ped pedb1 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[0][6]);
        Ped pedb2 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[1][6]);
        Ped pedb3 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[2][6]);
        Ped pedb4 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[3][6]);
        Ped pedb5 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[4][6]);
        Ped pedb6 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[5][6]);
        Ped pedb7 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[6][6]);
        Ped pedb8 = new Ped(0, Field.cells[7][6]);
        Ped pedn1 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[0][1]);
        Ped pedn2 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[1][1]);
        Ped pedn3 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[2][1]);
        Ped pedn4 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[3][1]);
        Ped pedn5 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[4][1]);
        Ped pedn6 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[5][1]);
        Ped pedn7 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[6][1]);
        Ped pedn8 = new Ped(1, Field.cells[7][1]);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Cell {
    int color;
    int x;
    int y;
    boolean full = false;
    public Cell (int color, boolean full, int x, int y) {
        this.color = color;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.full = full; }
    // setters
    protected void setColor(int c) {
        this.color = c; }
    protected void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x; }
    protected void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y; }
    protected void setFull(boolean set) {
        this.full = set; }
    // getters
    protected int getColor() {
        return this.color; }
    protected int getX(){
        return this.x; }
    protected int getY(){
        return this.y; }
    protected boolean isFull() {
        return this.full; }
protected Piece contains() {
    // What should I do?
    return null;
}
}
package chess;
public class Field {
    public Field(){
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){}
    protected static Cell cells[][] = new Cell[8][8];
    private int y=0;
    private int col = 0;
    // 0 = white, 1 = black
    protected void create() {
        // 0 = white, 1 = black
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++) {
            if (x%2 == 0) {
                if (y%2 == 0) {
                    col = 1;
                }
            } else {
                if(!(y%2 == 0)) {
                    col = 1;
                }
            }
            cells[x][y] = new Cell(col, false, x+1, y+1);
            y++; }
        //
    }
    }
package chess;
public abstract class Piece {
    protected boolean eaten = false;
    protected String name;
    protected int color;
    protected Cell cell;
    public Piece(String n, int pc, Cell c) {
        this.name = n;
        this.color = pc;
        this.cell = c;
    }
    protected void move(Field field, Piece p, Cell moveToCell) {
        field.move(p, moveToCell);
    }
    protected void eat(Field field, Cell eatPiece, Piece piece) {
        field.deleteItem(field, eatPiece);
        eatPiece.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Alf extends Piece {
    public Alf(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("Alf", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Horse extends Piece {
    public Horse(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("Horse", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class King extends Piece {
    public King(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("King", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Ped extends Piece {
    public Ped(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("Ped", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Queen extends Piece {
    public Queen(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("Queen", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
package chess;
public class Tower extends Piece {
    public Tower(int pc, Cell c) {
        super("Tower", pc, c);
        c.setFull(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should think a little more about your design, you data model. Currently the piece “knows” which cell (square) it is in, but the cell only knows whether there is a piece in it or not. Neither the pieces nor the cells know the entire board (field) nor all the pieces. For a cell to return the piece in that cell, that information must be somewhere. When the cell knows no pieces, it cannot get access to the information. I would find it more natural to have the cell know which piece is in it rather than the other way around (a `Piece` field in the `Cell` class) (or maybe you need both).

Comment: @OleV.V. So, to do that is cru3lgenius's answer a valid way or you meant an other thing?

Comment: That answer gives what appears to be the natural solution to the problem, and one I would probably go with. It solves the problem without changing the code you already have too much. The only downside seems to be that when moving a piece you will need to (1) remove it from the cell object where it was (2) update the piece to hold a reference to the new cell (3) in the new cell update the piece field to refer to the piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to store (in a variable) which "Piece" is on the specified cell and the method "contains" (I will call it getCurrentPiece) could return the name of the "Piece". For Example:

```
public class Cell {
   private Piece currentPiece;
   public void setPiece(Piece currPiece){
          this.currentPiece = currPiece;
   }
   public String getCurrentPiece(){
          return this.currentPiece.getName();
   }
```

And obviously then you will need a getName(); method in your "Piece" class. You may implement this like that:

```
public abstract class Piece {
    protected String getName(){
        return this.name;
}
```

Comment: You would want to have `currentPiece` instead of the `full` field in the question. You can still have the `isFull` method; it just returns true if there is a piece.

Comment: @OleV.V. I would want to have the `currentPiece` to know **which** object is there, not to know **if** there is an object there. So I need both methods

Comment: Sorry, @Luke, for being unclear. We will want to keep all the code from the answer. What I was trying to say, then we don’t want to keep the `full` field from the question since it would be redundant.